# Emitter doesn't emit the value

Tags: angular

I have a filter component as follows:

```
<app-filter (newStatusValue)="changeListByStatus($status)"
```

Problem is this doesn't output anything...

```
changeListByStatus($status){
  console.log('changeListByStatus', $status); // This doesn't output
}
```

In filter.component.html:

```
<select (ngModelChange)="filterByStatus($event)" [ngModel]="filterStatusValue">
    <option value="0" selected>All Status</option>
    ...
</select>
```

In filter.component.ts I emit the value coming from select:

```
@Output() newStatusValue : EventEmitter <string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
filterByStatus($status) {
  console.log('event: ', $status); // This ouputs
  this.newStatusValue.emit($status); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to as shown below. You are using $status. Angular doesn't know about it. You should use $event to get the event.

```
<app-filter (newStatusValue)="changeListByStatus($event)"

changeListByStatus(event){
  console.log('changeListByStatus', event); // This doesn't output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter for changeListByStatus should be $event.

```
<app-filter (newStatusValue)="changeListByStatus($event)"
```